# Why doesn't Haskell have a stronger alternative to Eq?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor, typeclass

The reason why `Set` is not a functor is given [here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/chad/snippets/random-code-snippets/set-is-not-a-functor). It seems to boil down to the fact that `a == b && f a /= f b` is possible. So, why doesn't Haskell have as standard an alternative to Eq, something like

```
class Eq a => StrongEq a where
    (===) :: a -> a -> Bool
    (/==) :: a -> a -> Bool
    x /== y = not (x === y)
    x === y = not (x /== y)
```

for which instances are supposed to obey the laws

```
∀a,b,f. not (a === b) || (f a === f b)
∀a. a === a
∀a,b. (a === b) == (b === a)
```

and maybe some others? Then we could have:

```
instance StrongEq a => Functor (Set a) where
    -- ...
```

Or am I missing something?

---

**Edit**: my problem is not “Why are there types without an `Eq` instance?”, like some of you seem to have answered. It's the opposite: “Why are there instances of `Eq` that aren't extensionally equal? Why are there too many `Eq` instances?”, combined with “If `a == b` does imply extensional equality, why is `Set` not an instance of `Functor`?”.

Also, my instance declaration is rubbish (thanks @n.m.). I should have said:

```
newtype StrongSet a = StrongSet (Set a)
instance Functor StrongSet where
    fmap :: (StrongEq a, StrongEq b) => (a -> b) -> StrongSet a -> StrongSet b
    fmap (StrongSet s) = StrongSet (map s)
```

Comment: I would argue that Michael's example is invalid. `==` _is_ supposed to witness "equivalent by all observable means" (that doesn't necessarily require `a == b` must hold only for _identical implementations_; but anything you can "officially" do with `a` and `b` should again yield equivalent results. So `unAlwaysEq` should never be exposed in the first place). If you can't ensure this for some type, you shouldn't give it an `Eq` instance.

Comment: If you define an instance that doesn't make sense, you should expect code you write to have strange behaviors. `Set` is not a functor because the output type of `Set.map` requires an `Ord` constraint. The instance `instance Functor (Set a) where ...` is not even valid.

Comment: In Scala there exists `fmap` for `Set`, and it has bitten me (and colleagues) many times.

Comment: How can your first property be true for any interesting type?  `Int` certainly couldn't be an instance of `StrongEq` because there exists an `f :: Int -> Int` where `a === b && not (f a === f b)`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I think you misread the formula (reading the implication in the wrong direction). There shouldn't be such an `f`. But there are `f` such that `a != B` and `f(a) == f(b)` (e.g. constant functions).

Comment: @ziggystar Can you explain. It sounds as if you have an answer.

Comment: @JamesWood The problem was always mapping a `Set` such that two elements that were different got mapped to be equal; but the intend was to retain duplicates. E.g. you have a set of objects and want to sum their cost. If you map the objects to their cost and then sum, if you get a set of the costs in between, you count objects with the same cost only once.

Comment: @ziggystar I'll look out for that! But the problem is still there with non-`Functor` `Data.Set.map`. Is the rule of thumb to never fold over a set?

Comment: @JamesWood My problem seems to be different from the linked argument against `Set` being a functor. And the rule of thumb for Scala sets is to "never map over `Set` (if what you want is to `fold`)". So folding is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second `Functor` instance also doesn't make any sense. The biggest reason why `Set` can't be a `Functor` in Haskell is `fmap` can't have constraints. Inventing different notions of equality as `StrongEq` doesn't change the fact that you can't write those constraints on `fmap` in your Set instance.

`fmap` in general *shouldn't* have the constraints you need. It makes perfect sense to have functors of functions, for example (without it the whole notion of using Applicative to apply functions inside a functor breaks down), and functions can't be members of Eq or your StrongEq in general.

`fmap` can't have extra constraints on only some instances, because of code like this:

```
fmapBoth :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b, c -> d) -> (f a, g c) -> (f b, g d)
fmapBoth (h, j) (x, y) = (fmap h x, fmap j y)
```

This code claims to work regardless of the functors `f` and `g`, and regardless of the functions `h` and `j`. It has no way of checking whether one of the functors is a special one that has extra constraints on `fmap`, nor any way of checking whether one of the functions it's applying would violate those constraints.

Saying that Set is a Functor in Haskell, is saying that there is a (lawful) operation `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b`, with that exact type. That is **precisely** what `Functor` means. `fmap :: (Eq a -> Eq b) => (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b` is not an example of such an operation.

It is possible, I understand, to use the [ConstraintKinds GHC extendsion](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html) to write a *different* Functor class that permits constraints on the values which vary by Functor (and what you actually need is an `Ord` constraint, not just `Eq`). [This blog post](http://jeltsch.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/the-constraint-kind/) talks about doing so to make a new Monad class which can have an instance for Set. I've never played around with code like this, so I don't know much more than that the technique exists. It wouldn't help you hand off Sets to existing code that needs Functors, but you should be able to use it instead of Functor in your own code if you wish.

Answer (score 15):

```
instance StrongEq a => Functor (Set a) where
```

This makes sense neither in Haskell nor in the grand mathematical/categorical scheme of things, regardless of what `StrongEq` means.

In Haskell, `Functor` requires a type constructor of kind `* -> *`. The arrow reflects the fact that in category theory, a functor is a kind of mapping. `[]` and (the hypothetical) `Set` are such type constructors. `[a]` and `Set a` have kind `*` and cannot be functors.

In Haskell, it is hard to define `Set` such that it can be made into a `Functor` because equality cannot be sensibly defined for some types no matter what. You cannot compare two things of type `Integer->Integer`, for example.

Let's suppose there is a function

```
goedel :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
goedel x y = -- compute the result of a function with 
             -- Goedel number x, applied to y
```

Suppose you have a value `s :: Set Integer`. What `fmap goedel s` should look like? How do you eliminate duplicates?

In your typical set theory equality is magically defined for everything, including functions, so `Set` (or `Powerset` to be precise) is a functor, no problem with that.

Comment: Okay, I understand the first bit. I would need `newtype StrongEq a => StrongSet a = StrongSet (Set a)` then `instance Functor StrongSet where ---`. But wouldn't your `goedel` cause a type error anyway? `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, but where `(a -> b) = (Integer -> (Integer -> Integer))` and `f = Set`, `f b`, namely `Set (Integer -> Integer)` doesn't exist (or the function that creates it doesn't exist). That's by design.

Comment: `goedel` does not cause a type error. It's a perfectly OK function. You will have a type error if you try to define `fmap` for `instance Functor StrongSet`.

Comment: Ah, so a functor must be able to contain any type. I guess that makes sense. Is that a standard thing in category theory functors?

Comment: @JamesWood, I'm no category theorist, but I doubt it. You'd presumably dealing with something like a functor whose domain is a *non-full* subcategory of Hask.

Answer (score 6):

Since I'm not a category theorist, I'll try to write a more concrete/practical explanation (i.e., one I can understand):

The key point is the one that @leftaroundabout made in a comment:

> `==` is supposed to
>   witness "equivalent by all observable means" (that doesn't necessarily
>   require `a == b` must hold only for identical implementations; but
>   anything you can "officially" do with a and b should again yield
>   equivalent results. So `unAlwaysEq` should never be exposed in the first
>   place). If you can't ensure this for some type, you shouldn't give it
>   an `Eq` instance.

That is, there should be no need for your `StrongEq` because *that's what `Eq` is supposed to be already*.

Haskell values are often intended to *represent* some sort of mathematical or "real-life" value. Many times, this representation is one-to-one. For example, consider the type

```
data PlatonicSolid = Tetrahedron | Cube |
   Octahedron | Dodecahedron | Icosahedron
```

This type contains exactly one representation of each Platonic solid. We can take advantage of this by adding `deriving Eq` to the declaration, and it will produce the correct instance.

In many cases, however, the same abstract value may be represented by more than one Haskell value. For example, the red-black trees `Node B (Node R Leaf 1 Leaf) 2 Leaf` and `Node B Leaf 1 (Node R Leaf 2 Leaf)` can both represent the set {1,2}. If we added `deriving Eq` to our declaration, we would get an instance of `Eq` that distinguishes things we want to be considered the same (outside of the implementation of the set operations).

It's important to make sure that types are only made instances of `Eq` (and `Ord`) when appropriate! It's very tempting to make something an instance of `Ord` just so you can stick it in a data structure that requires ordering, but if the ordering is not truly a *total* ordering of the abstract values, all manner of breakage may ensue. Unless the documentation absolutely guarantees it, for example, a function called `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` may not only be an *unstable* sort, but may not even produce a list containing all the Haskell values that go into it. `sort [Bad 1 "Bob", Bad 1 "James"]` can reasonably produce `[Bad 1 "Bob", Bad 1 "James"]`, `[Bad 1 "James", Bad 1 "Bob"]`, `[Bad 1 "James", Bad 1 "James"]`, or `[Bad 1 "Bob", Bad 1 "Bob"]`. All of these are perfectly legitimate. A function that uses `unsafePerformIO` in the back room to implement a Las Vegas-style randomized algorithm or to race threads against each other to get an answer from the fastest may even give different results different times, as long as they're `==` to each other.

tl;dr:  Making something an instance of `Eq` is a way of making a very strong statement to the world; don't make that statement if you don't mean it.

Answer (score 2):

This notion of `StrongEq` is tough. In general, equality is a place where computer science becomes significantly more rigorous than typical mathematics in the kind of way which makes things challenging.

In particular, typical mathematics likes to talk about objects as though they exist in a set and can be uniquely identified. Computer programs usually deal with types which are not always computable (as a simple counterexample, tell me what the set corresponding to the type `data U = U (U -> U)` is). This means that it may be undecidable as to whether two values are identifiable.

This becomes an enormous topic in dependently typed languages since typechecking requires identifying like types and dependently typed languages may have arbitrary values in their types and thus need a way to project equality.

So, `StrongEq` could be defined over a restricted part of Haskell containing only the types which can be decidably compared for equality. We can consider this a category with the arrows as computable functions and then see `Set` as an endofunctor from types to the type of sets of values of that type. Unfortunately, these restrictions have taken us far from standard Haskell and make defining `StrongEq` or `Functor (Set a)` a little less than practical.