# Are there any interesting commutative monads in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

Until I edited it today, the Haskell Wiki [claimed](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/index.php?title=What_a_Monad_is_not&oldid=57521) that `Maybe` is a commutative monad (actually, I think it still claims it somewhere). This is clearly wrong, because

```
do {a <- Nothing; b <- undefined; return (a,b)} === Nothing
```

while

```
do {b <- undefined; a <- Nothing; return (a,b)} === undefined
```

This failure of commutativity is actually rather important in real code: programmers rely on the fact that the computation will stop as soon as it reaches `Nothing`.

This leaves (among the monads described as commutative on the Haskell Wiki) only the `Reader` monad, which doesn't seem to do anything terribly exciting. That raised the question in my mind about whether there are any commutative monads in Haskell that are substantially different from `Reader`, aside from restrictions *of* `Reader`.

#### Edit

I just realized it's also possible to make a restricted `Writer` monad be commutative—it needs to accumulate values in some commutative monoid. Still not interesting.

Comment: `undefined` is kind of sort of cheating.  See: http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-et-al-popl2006.html.  You claim that an expression equals `undefined`.  But `undefined` isn't equal to anything.  It isn't a value.  You can't compare bottoms without solving the halting problem.

Comment: @nomen, `undefined` doesn't `==` anything, but in a general sense (based on denotational semantics) is often considered equal to any other bottom value.

Comment: Yes, and setting all bottoms as equal does not invalidate my point.  Indeed, if you mod out that equivalence relation, Haskell is total (as is the paper's point).  Now, my point is that it's kind of "cheating", insofar as you are using different semantics than the statement ("Maybe is commutative") had implicitly used.

Comment: @nomen, I don't know what you're getting at. Equating all bottoms still does not make `Nothing === bottom`.

Comment: If you exclude bottom, bottom isn't included...

Comment: [Haxl](https://github.com/facebook/Haxl) is a commutative monad. :)

Answer (score 6):

Statements like that sometimes have an implied "ignoring bottoms" requirement and this is probably one 
of those cases. It's commutative if we ignore bottoms. It's better to explicitly express that requirement though, because it can become important.

If we *do* ignore bottoms, then `Maybe` is a commutative Monad as well. Of course, as you mentioned in the question, bottoms are important to consider practically speaking, so it is good to be aware of the non-commutativity in their presence.

Comment: I think it's pretty fair to say that any categorical statement about Haskell (i.e., one about category theory in Haskell) implicitly ignores bottoms.

Comment: In many cases, the "bottoms break it" situation is a painful thing; in the case of `Maybe`, it's exactly what we want. Yes, it is good to recognize that when you can prove none of the actions are bottom (and that any pattern matching on their results never forces bottoms) then one can exchange the actions to improve efficiency/clarity. But by the time you get there, you're looking much more deeply into the specifics than the concept of "commutative monad" gets you.

Comment: @nomen: Right. I'd say that categorical statements in Haskell that hold even with bottoms are the exceptional cases (and not visa-versa), since it would have to take advantage of non-strict evaluation in a way that's often not possible for those sorts of things.

Comment: @DavidYoung, pardon my ignorance, but what makes commutativity "categorical"?

Comment: @dfeuer Well, monads come from category theory, so a commutative monad would be a categorical concept. But that isn't really my point. What I mean is that, regardless of category theory, a lot of times when you try to reason about Haskell programs in a formal way (such as showing commutativity), bottoms can get in the way. Sometimes it can be handy to look at properties that hold except when bottoms are involved, because bottoms can mess up a lot of things anyway. It can also be useful to examine at what point, exactly, a bottom will mess something up (how far you can evaluate something).

Comment: @dfeuer To prove that an equality law holds even with bottoms, you have to not only prove the law you set out to prove, you also pretty much have to prove that everything gets evaluated at exactly the same time on both sides of the equality which is usually a pain and it rules out some otherwise useful laws. Also, if an equality holds normally but not for bottoms, I would probably be more worried about which way is more efficient for long computations than worrying about the behavior wrt bottoms.

Comment: `Either` is not commutative.

Comment: @TomEllis: Oh yeah, I didn't think that through enough.

Answer (score 3):

The [set monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Set-Monad.html) qualifies as commutative and, IMO, interesting.

Comment: Oh, hah. I hadn't seen `set-monad` before. That's a clever solution to the problem.

Comment: Care to elaborate @leftaroundabout?

Comment: @gallais: you mean why it's commutative, or why some people might not consider it a monad?

Comment: @leftaroundabout the latter

Comment: @gallais: well, all the laws hold only WRT to what you eventually get with `run` (or comparison with `==`), whereas the internal representation is basically just a raw syntax tree and thus changes when you switch to an equivalent way of writing some expression. That's perfectly fine to me, but [apparently there isn't a universal consensus about which sense of equalness should be used for monad laws etc.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204340/why-doesnt-haskell-have-a-stronger-alternative-to-eq).