# What is the relation between ixmap, Array, and contravariant functor?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor, contravariance, category-theory

### tl;dr

Given the similarity between `ixmap`'s signature and `contramap`'s signature, I'd like to understand if `Array i e` is a contravariant functor in its first type argument or, at least, how the two things relate to each other from a category theory standpoint.

### Longer lucubration

At the end of [Chapter 12 from *Real World Haskell*](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/barcode-recognition.html), the function [`ixmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-Arr.html#v:ixmap) is used.

Based on its signature

```hs
ixmap :: (Ix i, Ix j) => (i, i) -> (i -> j) -> Array j e -> Array i e
```

I couldn't help but notice that, once we partially apply it to the first argument, e.g. we pass to it `(1 :: Int, 1 :: Int)` for simplicity, its signature becomes

```hs
ixmap (1 :: Int,1 :: Int) :: Ix j => (Int -> j) -> Array j e -> Array Int e
```

which has some similarity with the signature of [`contramap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#v:contramap):

```hs
contramap :: (a' -> a) -> f a -> f a'
```

and even more with the specialization of it for [`Op`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#v:Op):

```hs
contramap :: (a' -> a0) -> Op a a0 -> Op a a'
```

After all, I think, the type `Array j e` can be though of as the type of a function mapping a subset of type `j` to type `e`, kind of `j -> a` with a "restricted" `j`. So, just like `b -> a` is a `Functor` in `a` and `Op a b` was defined to make it a contravariant functor in `b`, I thought I could similarly define:

```hs
newtype Array' e i = Array' { arr :: Array i e }
```

and write a `Contravariant` instance for it:

```hs
instance Contravariant (Array' e) where
  contramap f a = undefined -- ???
```

What disturbs me is that I can't really use a partially applied `ixmap` for `contramap` because (1) what I do partially apply it to? And (2) doing it would block the `i` type (e.g. to `Int` in my example).

And I can't even think of a way for `contrampa` to retrie the required object of type `(i,i)` from the other two arguments `f :: (i -> j)` and `a :: Array j e`, because I have no function to go from `j` to `i`.

Comment: There is an additional issue: the `Ix i` constraint prevents the definition of `contramap` since the latter does not allow constraints. This is the same issue which prevents `Functor Set`, for instance, where we cannot add `Ord` as a requirement. I guess you will need a "constrained contravariant functor" typeclass, distinct from `Contravariant`.

Comment: @chi I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24226114/5825294) is a good explanation of you point?

Comment: Yes, that's the point.

Answer (score 4):

`Array` is a [profunctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profunctor) from the category of index-remapping functions into the normal **Hask** category (unconstrained Haskell types with Haskell functions as morphisms).

There is a fairly widespread [class for profunctors **Hask** → **Hask**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.6.2/docs/Data-Profunctor.html), but it has no way to express the `Ix` constraint. That could easily be expressed<sup>†</sup> in the [constrained-categories](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0) framework though:

```
class (Category r, Category t) => Profunctor p r t where
  dimap :: (Object r a, Object r b, Object t c, Object t d)
     => r a b -> t c d -> p b c -> p a d
```

Now, to actually use this with `Array`, we need to lift the ranges of allowed indices into the type level. I.e. instead of using `Int` as the index type – which is kind of unsafe, because it allows indexing outside the range... we clearly can't have that in a category theory setting! – we use only a type that has the allowed range baked in. Rather than actually hacking this into `Array`, let me use `Vector` (which doesn't bother offering different index types at all) as the low-level representation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (Nat, natVal)
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector as V

newtype Range (lb :: Nat) (ub :: Nat)
     = Range { getIndexInRange :: Int -- from 0 to ub-lb-1
             }

newtype SafeArray i a = SafeArray {
    getFlattenedArray :: Vector a  -- length must equal `rangeLength @i`
  }

class ToLinearIndex r where
  rangeLength :: Int
  toLinearIndex :: r -> Int

instance ∀ lb ub . ToLinearIndex (Range lb ub) where
  rangeLength = fromInteger $ natVal @rb [] - natVal @lb []
  toLinearIndex = getIndexInRange
instance ∀ rx ry . (ToLinearIndex rx, ToLinearIndex ry)
     => ToLinearIndex (rx, ry) where
  rangeLength = rangeLength @rx * rangeLength @ry
  toLinearIndex (ix, iy)
      = toLinearIndex ix + rangeLength @rx * toLinearIndex iy

(!) :: ToLinearIndex i => SafeArray i a -> i -> a
SafeArray v ! i = V.unsafeIndex v $ toLinearIndex i

newtype IxMapFn r s = IxMapFn {
   getIxMapFn :: Int -> Int  -- input and output must be <rangeLength
                             -- of `r` and `s`, respectively
  }

instance Category IxMapFn where
  type Object IxMapFn i = ToLinearIndex i
  id = IxMapFn id
  IxMapFn f . IxMapFn g = IxMapFn $ f . g

saDiMap :: ∀ r s a b . (ToLinearIndex r, ToLinearIndex s)
      => IxMapFn s r -> (a -> b) -> SafeArray r a -> SafeArray s b
saDiMap (IxMapFn f) g (SafeArray v)
    = SafeArray . V.generate (rangeLength @s)
       $ g . V.unsafeIndex v . f

instance Profunctor SafeArray IxMapFn (->) where
  dimap = saDimMap
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>I've never gotten around to adding a profunctor class to `constrained-categories`, mostly because I think profunctors are a bit of an abused abstraction in Haskell: often when people use endo-profunctors, what they actually mean to express is simply a category / [`Arrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html).</sub>

Comment: Arrow requires you to include at least all of Hask in your semantic object (because of `arr` and its laws). This turns out to be an actual problem for a lot of useful would-be instances, so the fact that profunctor doesn't require it is nice in that regard.

Comment: Also: while this deals with the `Ix` constraint, does it deal with the other objection in the question, namely, that there's no good way to choose the bounds of the output array in `contramap`? In particular, does the code you posted here actually typecheck?

Comment: @DanielWagner right, indeed it's quite a bit more involved – the allowed range needs to be lifted into the type level. See edit. — Regarding `Arrow` – yeah, that class is too strong. I wish that was a more fine-grained hierarchy of category classes. Well, that's why I normally use my own...